# python-dev package installation error

Tags: linux, apt, package-management, python

```
Package python-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  python2-dev python2 python-dev-is-python3

E: Package 'python-dev' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package libcapstone3
```

Comment: What distro & version are you using?   On Debian (and most derivatives), the `python-dev` package has been renamed to `python2-dev` (and while `python2` is still supported, most future work is focused on `python3`).  Also note that Debian no longer even has `libcapstone3`, it currently has `libcapstone4` and `libcapstone-dev` version 4.0.2-5 (and `python3-capstone`)

Comment: Please supply the command you are running that generates the error messages you posted (e.g., `apt-get install python-dev`).

Answer (score 5):

`python-dev` is no longer available since Debian 11, Ubuntu 20.10, and any distribution derived from those. If you need Python 2 you can try `python2-dev` instead, but note that Python 2 is no longer supported by the Python community, and many modules are only available for Python 3 in Debian and Ubuntu.

`libcapstone3` is also obsolete, current releases of Debian, Ubuntu and derivatives ship `libcapstone4`. If you’re trying to build software using this library, you should install `libcapstone-dev`; if you’re looking for the Python module, install `python3-capstone` (it’s only available for Python 3).

Comment: Any link for the source of this? I do not find anything on Python website

Comment: @mukesh.kumar which part are you interested in? If it’s the `python-dev` removal, see [this changelog](https://tracker.debian.org/news/1164934/accepted-python-defaults-2718-1-source-into-unstable/). Note that this question is about Python packaging in Debian and derivatives, the Python web site isn’t relevant.

Comment: Thanks, I was indeed looking at the wrong place.